# LISP: take an arbitrary s-expression and reverse every cons node (car and cdr of a node) recursively

Tags: list, lisp, cons

So in lisp a list is a collection of cons nodes, each node has two parts to it.  The car of the node and the cdr of that node, how would I go about reversing each cons node?

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and output you want? We're having some trouble figuring out the desired behavior here.

Answer (score 2):

Using reduce:

```
(defun reverse-conses (list)
  (reduce (lambda (x acc) (cons acc x)) list :initial-value nil :from-end t))
```

Recursively:

```
(defun reverse-conses (list)
  (if (null list) nil
      (cons (reverse-conses (cdr list)) (car list))))
```

Comment: I don't think this does what is desired -- for example, `(reverse-conses '((1 . 2)))` returns `(NIL 1 . 2)`, not `((2 . 1))`.

Comment: @zck, it depends on how one reads the question. My solution works as I intended. While the first half of the first sentence might be read as if it's about a list *containing* cons cells (but note the "in lisp", which indicates that it's about Lisp lists in general), the rest clearly talks about *nodes*, which I interpreted as the constituent cons cells of the list *itself*. Let's wait until the OP clarifies.

Comment: And, btw, now that I'm reading the question again, the title says *recursively*. But I'll wait for further clarification before I change my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it could be specified better. Let's hope that happens.

Comment: Then again, I'll be offline for the next 10 hours. Added a recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting with a single function that swaps a cons cell.

```
(defun swap-cons (cns)
  (cons (cdr cns)
        (car cns)))
```

Let's test it:

```
> (swap-cons (cons 1 2))
(2 . 1)
> (swap-cons (cons 1 (cons 2 3)))
((2 . 3) . 1)
```

So this works. Now we just need to map this function over the input list

```
(defun swap-conses (lst)
  (mapcar #'swap-cons
       lst))

> (swap-conses '((1 . 2)))
((2 . 1))
> (swap-conses '((1 . 2) (3 . 4)))
((2 . 1) (4 . 3))
> (swap-conses '((1 2)))
(((2) . 1))
> (swap-conses '((1 . 2) (3 4) (5 6 7)))
((2 . 1) ((4) . 3) ((6 7) . 5))
```

Comment: The title and description of this question talk about different things. It's not especially clear what @user3011240 wants.

Answer (score 0):

To recursively go through a whole tree and swap `car` and `cdr` you can do something like this:

```
(defun reverse-conses (tree)
  (if (consp tree)
      (cons (reverse-conses (cdr tree))
            (reverse-conses (car tree)))
      tree))

(reverse-conses (cons 1 2))   ; ==> (2 . 1)
(reverse-conses '(1 2 3))     ; ==> (((nil . 3) . 2) . 1)
(reverse-conses '(1 (2 3) 4)) ; ==> (((nil . 4) (nil . 3) . 2) . 1)
```

Considering the argument can consist of improper lists there isn't a simpler solution to this.